# Get Excel Cell Address without $ in Delphi 2009

Tags: excel, delphi

I am writing a delphi program that needs to get the address of the cell without dollor sign(absolute reference). According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address#syntax, all I need to do is to set the first two parameters to false e.g. myRange.address(false,false) but the debugger returns "member not found". Is there anything wrong with the statement?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] including how you instantiate Excel

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have figured it out. The parameters must be enclosed by [] instead of ().

Thank you everyone.